# Finding if a function is Concave or Convex

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have the function $C=TQ^{\frac{1}{a}} + F$. Where $C$ is total cost, $Q$ is output, $a$ is a positive parametric constant, $F$ is fixed cost, and $T$ measures the technology available to the firm (Parameter). We also know that $T > 0$.

I understand how to solve grahpically, and I know how to use dividens, but I do not know how to set up the equation in a matter to solve for it.

I tried subbing $T$ with $1$, $A$ with $0.99$ and $F$ with $1$ but I am still lost. Could someone help me please ): .

A hint is to use calculus of optimization, and to check our second-order condition.

Comment: Do you know what is meant by second-order condition?

Comment: No I do not, isnt it to find the max or min?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is to test if the function is convex or concave in $Q$. A (twice differentiable) function of one variable is convex in some interval if its second derivative is positive in that interval. That is what we call the second-order condition.

So in this case

$$
\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial Q^2} = T\left( \frac{1}{a} \right)\left( \frac{1}{a} -1\right)Q^{1/a-2}
$$
Assuming that $Q \geq 0$, this is positive if $a \leq1$. So $C$ is convex for $a \leq 1$ and concave for $a>1$